# PHPUnit in symfony2 fails on JSON request without error message

Tags: php, json, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to call a page that returns JSON. This is the response sent by the controller

```php
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($result);
    $response->send();
    exit;
```

When I test it with phpunit, with this code:

```php
    $publicClient = static::createClient();
    $publicClient->request('POST', '/list/', []);
    $this->assertTrue(true);
```

the **assert is never reached**. Instead the ouptut (with --debug and -v) is simply

```bsh
bin/phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist --debug -v
PHPUnit 4.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/eliphi/public_html/app/phpunit.xml.dist


Starting test '[...]\Tests\Controller\FrontendControllerTest::testListAjax'.
[{"seriesTitle":"public","publications":[]},{"seriesTitle":"member","publications":[]},{"seriesTitle":"abo","publications":[]},{"seriesTitle":"public Magazine","publications":[]},{"seriesTitle":"member Magazine","publications":[]},{"seriesTitle":"abo Magazine","publications":[]}]
```

*That's all!* When I call the page from the browser, the response header is correctly set with

```
Date: Sat, 01 Nov 2014 14:56:31 GMT    
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.34-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1    
Cache-Control: no-cache    
Connection: close    
Content-Type: application/json    

200 OK
```

If I do a request on a different url that returns html, it works just fine. What could possibly be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `exit` call in the controller is terminating the test script.  In general, you should use `return` instead.

Exiting from a controller will break tests and bypass any post-controller events set up - it may have unexpected results if you use any third party bundles.